# Get the evidence as video/movie in Calabash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calabash, calabash-ios, calabash-android

I am a newbie of Calabash ( Automation Testing tool) .
Regrading the evidence with calabash, as far as I know we just can take a picture/screenshot only.
However with some function/input I'd like to record a video to confirm the inputting/tranfering...
Can we do the generate evidence as video with Calabash ?
Please help me if you know...  Thank you so much

Comment: Is it related to RubyonRails?

Comment: ＠Pavan : Yes, exactly.

Comment: I have already contacted with supporter of Calabash. Unfortunately, he said Calabash-ios can not do that anymore. But Android is OK.
It's OK. That all ! Should be closed this question !
Thank all

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use some kind of program to take videos like OBS(i know its for brodcast but also is free and can record) from genymotion emulator in window mode to capture your test steps